# get list XML of approval status for pages and component

Tags: 2011, 2013, 2011-sp1

I have to get list of xml for Approval status for component and pages by applying ApprovalStatusData Filter....how can I do this?

i have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
 var publicationTarget = (PublicationTargetData)client.Read(id, new ReadOptions());
 var approvalStatus = (ApprovalStatusData)client.Read(
                                      publicationTarget.MinApprovalStatus.IdRef, new ReadOptions());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all of the approval statuses by doing something like:

```
var approvalStatuses = client.GetSystemWideList(new ApprovalStatusesFilterData);
```